# Parsing nested JSON from aws SNS message

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-web-services

I'm having trouble returning `errorMessage` from this nested JSON response I get from an aws SNS message.  Part of the problem, I think, is the weird spaces and formatting this is returned in. I parsed the whole thing once to get `message` which I'm able to return values like `executionId`from, but `JSON.parse(message.errorData)` already throws me an error before I can continue downward to -> `Cause` -> `errorMessage`.

```
{"executionId":"<<ARN REDACTED>>","stateName":"9b44bafc-d542-4533-8091-5c9a2bfd9983","startTime":"2022-04-07T16:20:59.350Z","sourceStepFunction":"<<REDACTED>>","errorData":{"Error":"Error","Cause":"{\"errorType\":\"Error\",\"errorMessage\":\"Request failed with status code 400\",\"trace\":[\"Error: Request failed with status code 400\",\"    at e.exports (/var/task/index.js:2:69443)\",\"    at e.exports (/var/task/index.js:2:71859)\",\"    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:2:62409)\",\"    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:412:35)\",\"    at IncomingMessage.emit (domain.js:475:12)\",\"    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1334:12)\",\"    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)\"]}"}}
```

Comment: `message.errorData` is not a JSON-encoded string. The thing you need to parse is `message.errorData.Cause`.

Comment: @Parsifal so if I set a variable to `JSON.parse(message.errorData.Cause)` and then take `var.errorMessage` it should return properly?

Comment: You don't show any of you code, so I can't make that guarantee, but based on the message you provided that should work.

Comment: For problems like this, I recommend using `jq` or some other tool to pretty-print the JSON. It makes it a lot easier to see what's real JSON and what's string-encoded.